# Find couples of frames $B\neq B_1$ with 5 elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are (i) PRR equivalent, (ii) similar, and (iii) unitary equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

1. Find couples of frames $B\neq B_1$ with 5 elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are (i) PRR equivalent, (ii) similar, and (iii) unitary equivalent. Assume that the frames do not contain the vector 0 or parallel vectors.
2. Find two frames $B \neq B_1$ which are PRR equivalent, similar and unitary equivalent.
3. Show that two Parseval frames are similar if and only if are unitary equivalent.

PRR equivalent is permutation, rotations, and reflection equivalent. Other than that I do not really understand how to find two frames that are PRR equivalent.

Similar equivalent means that the matrix of the frames must satisfy the following: $B=PB_1P^{-1}$.

And lastly, Unitary equivalent means that $B^{-1}=B^T$.

How would I start this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Parts (i) and (ii):}$

Let $T(x,y,z)=(-x,-y,-z)$ and $T^{-1}(x,y,z)=(-x,-y,-z)$. So where both $B_1$ and $B_2$, as shown below, are PRR equivalent, similar, and unitary equivalent.

$B_1=\begin{Bmatrix} 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2\end{Bmatrix}$ and $B_2=\begin{Bmatrix} -2 & -2 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & -2 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -2\end{Bmatrix}$

$\textbf{Show that two Parseval frames are similar $\iff$ are unitary equivalent.}$

$\Rightarrow$ : Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^k$ and $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^k$  be two Parseval frames such that $Tx_i=y_i$ for $i=1,2, \dots,k$ for some invertible operator T from $\mathscr{H}$ onto $\mathscr{K}$. Then for each $y \in \mathscr{K}$, we have $$\|T^*y\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^k|\langle T^*y,x_i \rangle |^2=\sum_{i=1}^k|\langle y,Tx_i \rangle |^2=\sum_{i=1}^k|\langle y,y_i \rangle |^2=\|y\|^2$$ This proves that the operator $T^*$ is an isometry. From a previous proposition, this means that $TT^*=I$. We also know, however, that T is an invertible operator. Therefore, $T^*=T^{-1}$, which proves that T is unitary.

$\Leftarrow$ : Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^k$ and $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^k$  be two Parseval frames such that T is unitary. (i.e. $T^*=T^{-1}$) Since T is unitary it is an invertible operator. By a previous proposition if $T^*=T^{-1}$ then $T^*T=TT^*=I$. So $T=T^*(TT^*)^{-1}T$ is an invertible operator from $\mathscr{H}$ onto $\mathscr{K}$. (i.e. T is an isometry, which means $\|Tx_i\|=\|x_i\|$.) To show that T is similar we need to show $Tx_i=y_i$. Hence 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\|Tx_i\|^2 & =\sum_{i=1}^k |\langle Tx_i,y_i\rangle|^2=\sum_{i=1}^k|\langle x_i,T^*y_i\rangle |^2 \\
\|x_i\|^2 & =\sum_{i=1}^k |\langle x_i,x_i \rangle|^2 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
This two statements are equivalent if $T*y_i=x_i$ but since T is unitary then $Tx_i=y_i$. Hence T is similar.